# c++ converting a string containing UTC date & time to a tm struct

Tags: c++, windows, datetime

I have the following function which takes a UTC? formatted string and should convert it into a tm struct.

```
tm utc_string_to_dt(std::wstring sTime)
{
    static const std::wstring dateTimeFormat{ L"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S" };

    std::wstringstream ss{ sTime };
    std::tm dt;

    ss >> std::get_time(&dt, dateTimeFormat.c_str());

    // corrections to the returned values. Brain dead year counts from 1900
    dt.tm_year = dt.tm_year + 1900;             // year counted from 1900
    dt.tm_mon = dt.tm_mon + 1;                  // month starts from 0 (not 1)

    return dt;
}
```

If I give it the string '2011-09-30T19:46:01.000Z' I get a date and time back of 30th Sept 2011 19:46:01 however if it gets a string "2011-08-30T10:00:00+01:00 I get back 30th August 2011 00:00:00 - the time part is being set to midnight. How can I convert the latter string accurately. I am using VS2013 on windows.

Comment: Don't "correct" the values of `tm_year` and `tm_mon` in the `tm`. If you do that you can no longer correctly pass it to things that expect `tm` structs. You only need to do those additions for display. And why are you adding `static` to the declaration of `dateTimeFormat`? It's unnecessary.

Comment: The `static` is so that `dateTimeFormat` is initialized the first time `utc_string_to_dt()` is called, and then reused as-is every subsequent time. This is a perfectly valid use of a `static` local variable without declaring it as a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

How are you outputting it/checking what the value is, and what is the time zone set to on your computer?

I'm not seeing what you're seeing. Given this code, slightly modified from yours:

```
const std::wstring dateTimeFormat{ L"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S" };

tm utc_string_to_dt(std::wstring sTime)
{
    std::wstringstream ss{ sTime };
    std::tm dt;

    ss >> std::get_time( &dt, dateTimeFormat.c_str() );
    return dt;
}

int main()
{

    tm x = utc_string_to_dt( L"2011-08-30T10:00:00+01:00" );

    std::cout << x.tm_year + 1900 << '/' << x.tm_mon + 1 << '/' << x.tm_mday << "\n"
        << x.tm_hour << ':' << x.tm_min << ':' << x.tm_sec << "\n";

    std::wcout << std::put_time( &x, dateTimeFormat.c_str() );

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output:

```
2011/8/30
10:0:0
2011-08-30T10:00:00
```

I suspect that the method of output is adjusting the time.